# Setting QSpinBox text style in qss

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets

I already checked the Qt [examples](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qspinbox) and related Stack Overflow questions, I want to personalize a QSpinBox via qss to appear like [image: this].

I already customized the buttons of the QSpinBox, but need help to set the text background, i have this: [image]